# $C^1$ diffeomorphism, but not $C^\infty$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Can you think of a $C^1$ bijection $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f^{-1}$ also of class $C^1$ but $f$ is not of class $C^\infty$?

I have been trying to construct one from some usual examples of $C^1$ functions that are not $C^\infty$ (like $x\mapsto \mid x\mid^3$), but they are not even bijective or defined on all $\mathbb{R}$. And also some usual examples of smooth homeomorphisms that are not diffeomorphisms (like $x\mapsto x^3$) do not do the job here because their inverse is not even differentiable.

Comment: Inverse is not differentiable at 0 I think

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I missed that part of your problem.  Deleted.

Comment: Isn't it enough to glue some arcs of parabolas?

Comment: $$ f(x)= x+\frac{1}{2}\text{Re}\,\text{Li}_3(e^{ix})$$ should do the job nicely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need much change to your examples to make them work, you only have to make sure the derivative isn't zero anywhere. For instance, $f(x) = x|x|+x$ is differentiable and has differentiable inverse, but is not smooth.

**Edit:** Details to address @stresset-out's comment:

The inverse of this function is given by
$$
f^{-1}(y) = \cases{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4y}}{2} & if $y\leq 0$\\\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4y}}{2}& if $y>0$}
$$and we can see that this definition avoids any problematic points with the square roots.

Comment: @stressed-out No worries. I'm writing an edit right now.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(x) = \int_0^x(1+|t|)\, dt$ has this property.